# Making Certificate with User detail in android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to make certificate with user detail in android studio.  And user can download there certificate .(JAVA)

Comment: What do you mean by a "certificate"? What kind? Also, please indicate what you have tried (with code) and post the logcat (if you're getting any errors). If you haven't already tried it yourself, go ahead and try it first. If you're stuck even after searching online, come back with what you have and explain in detail what issue you're having.

Comment: I want to make certificate type image  with the details that user gave . And user can download it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you can do this.

1. Create a template of certificate .html like this:-

   body{
            font-size: 12px !important;
        }
    
    
        
            
                
                    {{var_profile}}

   {{full_name}}

   {{address}}

   Tel: {{var_tel_number}}
2. By using PHP or anything you are using, you can replace the `var_profile` , `full_name` and others to your use case.
3. Call them at the Android application as `Webview`.
4. Make a download button to download as PDF format.